# Transfer data from form and save data with Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I currently have a problem with jQuery and Ajax – maybe you can help me....

**What I intend to do:**
I have an edit button. If this button is pressed, a new form should be displayed below the button.
After pressing the submit button, I want to write the data form the form in the database (with ajax).

**This works in the moment:**
-   Show the form below the button, if the edit button is pressed
-   Save the data in the database (with fix values), if I press the submit button

**Problem:**
But I can´t write data in the database with committed datas:

```
        var edit-phone = jQuery("#edit-phone-number").val();
        var edit-language = jQuery("#edit-language").val();




function edit_data_db($phone_id){

var phone_id    = $phone_id;
var id_element = "row_" + phone_id;
var edit_btn = "edit_" + phone_id;


$( "<tr><td class='form-edit-data' colspan='4'><h3>Update Data</h3></br><form><lable>Phone Number</lable><input type='text' name='edit-phone-number' id='edit-phone-number' placeholder='Phone number' required> </br> </br><lable>Language</lable><input type='text' name='edit-language' id='edit-language' placeholder='Language' required></br> </br><button class='button' type='submit' name='senden' id='edit-submit'>Submit</button></form></td></tr>" ).insertAfter( "#"+id_element );

jQuery("#edit-submit").click(function( ){

        //Form Data - Problem
        var edit-phone = jQuery("#edit-phone-number").val();
        var edit-language = jQuery("#edit-language").val();

        console.log(edit-language);
        console.log(edit-phone);            

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                    action: 'edit_data_db', 
                    'phone-id':"80", 
                    'edit-phone-number':"4", 
                    'edit-language':"1"
                    },
            dataType:"json",    
            success: function(data){
                jQuery('.messageDiv').html(data.message);



            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        return false;

});
};
```

Comment: `var edit-language = ...` is a syntax error, also there is no HTML element `<lable>`, and  `</br>` is wrong, it should either be `<br/>` or `<br>` (preferred).

Comment: you are passing some fixed data to the ajax. The behaviour you describe is correct

Comment: what I'd do is to create a form on the page and hide it. When you want to edit values display the form and populate it with values. Submit the form with ajax. this way you will have just one form and just one submit function

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks a lot - the syntax error (var edit-language = ...) was the mistake.

Comment: You can use http://jshint.com  to check your code for such (and other) avoidable errors. Many code editors also have syntax checker built in.